# Getting BT Notifier application to link U8 Smart Watch with No Carrier Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7

I have a Google Nexus 7, no SIM card, tablet. I recently acquired a [U8 Smart Watch](http://www.gearbest.com/cell-phones/pp_28983.html). The app that the watch recommends to download to link the two devices, "BT Notifier", apparently [no longer exists](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oinom.btnotification&hl=zh-CN). The [replacement app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bt.smartwatch&hl=en_GB), as found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2E-vQy5BM0), is marked as incompatible with my tablet, with some poking around online suggesting that they've labeled it as only able to be used with Android phones.

How do I get this application to work? Since I don't do phone calls, I have no real need for things like viewing call logs on my phone, but it would be nice to be able to use my watch to change things on my tablet, such as the currently playing song, when jogging (as otherwise, I'd have to pull my backpack around, unearth the tablet, etc).

I am working on a rooted Nexus 7 with OS of 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the [V8 Plus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0158CCLFG).  I couldn't get it to pair to my Nexus 5 stock with the BT Notifier.  However, it did pair with both of these applications

[MediaTek Smart Device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtk.btnotification&hl=en)

[FunDo Smart Device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.szfunyundevice.btnotification&hl=en)

Both those applications look very similar once they're installed.

Once it paired I could make calls from the watch, remotely trigger the phone camera, see text messages, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither work for me with my U8, but thank you for trying.